# TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined at Object ClientApp\dist\main-server.js

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, typescript2.0

I am getting an exception on my angular 4 asp.net core2 project
**NodeInvocationException:**

> Prerendering failed because of error: TypeError:
>
> Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined at Object
> ClientApp\dist\main-server.js in Angular 4 project asp.net core

**Below is the stack trace**

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Kodjo\Documents\GitHub\DMS2.0\WebApplicationAngular\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:76908:26)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\Kodjo\Documents\GitHub\DMS2.0\WebApplicationAngular\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (C:\Users\Kodjo\Documents\GitHub\DMS2.0\WebApplicationAngular\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:46230:23)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\Kodjo\Documents\GitHub\DMS2.0\WebApplicationAngular\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (C:\Users\Kodjo\Documents\GitHub\DMS2.0\WebApplicationAngular\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:15943:30)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\Kodjo\Documents\GitHub\DMS2.0\WebApplicationAngular\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (C:\Users\Kodjo\Documents\GitHub\DMS2.0\WebApplicationAngular\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:15103:34)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\Kodjo\Documents\GitHub\DMS2.0\WebApplicationAngular\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (C:\Users\Kodjo\Documents\GitHub\DMS2.0\WebApplicationAngular\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:40629:30)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\Kodjo\Documents\GitHub\DMS2.0\WebApplicationAngular\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30)
```

**Current directory is:** C:\Users\Kodjo\Documents\GitHub\DMS2.0\WebApplicationAngular

```
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.HttpNodeInstance.<InvokeExportAsync>d__7`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.OutOfProcessNodeInstance.<InvokeExportAsync>d__13`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.NodeServicesImpl.<InvokeExportWithPossibleRetryAsync>d__10`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.NodeServicesImpl.<InvokeExportWithPossibleRetryAsync>d__10`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Prerendering.PrerenderTagHelper.<ProcessAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.<RunAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at AspNetCore._Views_Home_Index_cshtml.<ExecuteAsync>d__12.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Kodjo\Documents\GitHub\DMS2.0\WebApplicationAngular\Views\Home\Index.cshtml:line 2
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.<RenderPageCoreAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.<RenderPageAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.<RenderAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__21.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.<ExecuteResultAsync>d__26.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeResultAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at WebApplicationAngular.Startup.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<<Configure>b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Kodjo\Documents\GitHub\DMS2.0\WebApplicationAngular\Startup.cs:line 102
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack.ConditionalProxyMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack.ConditionalProxyMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

Thanks

Fabrice

Comment: Add the stacktrace for the error. You can do this by going to the correct line and placing a breakpoint. I imagine though this will probably help you realize what is wrong.

Comment: I have added the stack trace.

Comment: Have you gone to this file, line and character to see what object is undefined?

C:\Users\Kodjo\Documents\GitHub\DMS2.0\WebApplicationAngular\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:76908:26

Comment: I've got the same error and can't figure it out.  Did you get any further?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have solve it by changing the asp-prerenderer-module to asp-ng2-prerenderer-module inside View/Home/index.html . Even though I don't know yet the impact everything seems to work fine. Hope that helps